# Movie catalog like imdb

Tags: database, movie, catalog, imdb

Someone knows a movie catalog open source software? I want to make a site like http://www.cinenacional.com/peliculas and before start to develop en whole site from scratch I'd like to know if someone knows a webapp similar to imdb or http://www.cinenacional.com/

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the API at http://www.themoviedb.org/.

Flixster/Rotten Tomatoes also offers an API: http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/.

I hope this helps.

Comment: RT is no longer available